# Custom filter Api platform with or and between

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I use the plugin FullCalendar on my front side, and I need to fetch the events (I have an entity `Event`) based on the different rules :

- `startAt` between start and end of Fullcalendar range
- or `endAt` between start and end of Fullcalendar range

To have all cases.

I started with DateFilter, but it won't work since I need an `or`.

I started to create a custom Filter, but I need to apply to apply the filter on 2 properties (`startAt` and `endAt`), and I don't see any documentation on how to use an `or` between them. For now, they just cumulate the filters.

I read this thread too: https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/639

Can I do this ? Or do I need to work with extensions ?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve it with a custom filter. The names of the fields in the database are startDate and endDate.

Entity: `* @ApiFilter(FullCalendarDateFilter::class, properties={"start", "end"})`

Filter:

```
<?php

namespace App\Filter;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\AbstractFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Util\QueryNameGeneratorInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\PropertyInfo\Type;

final class FullCalendarDateFilter extends AbstractFilter
{

private $dates = [];

protected function filterProperty(string $property, $value, QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, QueryNameGeneratorInterface $queryNameGenerator, string $resourceClass, string $operationName = null, array $context = [])
{
    // otherwise filter is applied to order and page as well
    if (!in_array($property, ['start', 'end'])) {
        return;
    }
    $property = $property . "Date";
    if (
        !$this->isPropertyEnabled(str_replace('Date', '', $property), $resourceClass) ||
        !$this->isPropertyMapped($property, $resourceClass)
    ) {
        return;
    }
    $this->dates[$property] = $value;
    if (array_key_exists('endDate', $this->dates)) {
        $queryBuilder
            ->andWhere('o.startDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate OR o.endDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate')
            ->setParameters(
                [
                    'startDate' => $this->dates['startDate'],
                    'endDate' => $this->dates['endDate'],
                ]
            );
    }
}

// This function is only used to hook in documentation generators (supported by Swagger and Hydra)
public function getDescription(string $resourceClass): array
{
    if (!$this->properties) {
        return [];
    }

    $description = [];
    foreach ($this->properties as $property => $strategy) {
        $description["$property"] = [
            'property' => $property,
            'type' => Type::BUILTIN_TYPE_STRING,
            'required' => false,
            'description' => 'FullCalendar filter!',
            'openapi' => [
                'example' => 'YYYY-mm-dd',
                'allowReserved' => false, // if true, query parameters will be not percent-encoded
                'allowEmptyValue' => true,
                'explode' => false, // to be true, the type must be Type::BUILTIN_TYPE_ARRAY, ?product=blue,green will be ?product=blue&product=green
            ],
        ];
    }

    return $description;
}
}
```